# JSONAssert.assertEquals(objActual, jObject, true) is not working as expected

Tags: java, json, assertion, jsonassert

I need to assert two JSON Objects, for that I am using JSONAssert jar.

```
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
.
.//some code
.
JSONAssert.assertEquals(obj1, jObject, true);
```

When the control reaches JSONAssert line, the execution just stops.
I am passing 'obj1' a json object from converting a json string and is in form {"a":1} and the second argument is picked from a txt file and is in format {"a":2}.

Assertion error is expected but nothing happens, no error ... nothing.

When trying the jsonAssert jar in a independent java program where json objects are initialised there itself, it works fine.

Any suggestions will be helpful, Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that `obj1` and `jObject` are what you expect?

Comment: Well ... i printed them and they print as json object

Comment: like {"a":1} and {"a":2}

Comment: Have you tried to change `true` to `false`?

Comment: just tried ..no change

Comment: Works for me. Can you run a minimum example like `JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject("{\"a\":1}"); JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("{\"a\":2}"); JSONAssert.assertEquals(obj1, jObject, true);`

Comment: yeah tried this , seperatly it is working for me too, in my code it is not

Comment: OK, then you'll have to show us the code which creates obj1 and jObject. The problem must be in there.

Comment: Is there a surrounding try-catch block? Maybe you catch a Throwable and do nothing with it...

Comment: no thats not the issue

Comment: surprisingly, for me it worked when change the strict mode from false to true, it worked, if i set it to false then it throws exception

Answer (score -1):

`JSONAssert.assertEquals` would throw an `AssertionError` in the actual JSON doesn't "match" the expected one.

Or, if one of the JSONs can't be parsed, it would throw a `JSONException`.

One possible problem is that you have some `catch (Throwable e)` clause which "silences" the assertion error and/or parse exception.